# Find limits with natural logs

Tags: calculus, limits

I have problem with calculating such limits:

1)

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{\ln(3n^2+20n+5)}{\ln(n^9-3n+12)}$

wolfram shows it's equal to $\frac{2}{9}$ so it suggest we take the quotient of highest exponent but I don't know how show it.

2)

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{n^2}}$

here I tried to use $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and compare it with $1$ but without result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SimonS already answered (1), using the simplest argument which is that $$\ln(3n^2 + 20n + 5) = 2\ln(n) + \ln(3 + 20/n + 5/n^2)=2\ln(n)+O(1),$$ and $$\ln(n^9 - 3n + 12) = \ln(n^9) + \ln(1 - 3/n^8 + 12/n^9)=9\ln(n)+O(1).$$ 
To solve (2), note that, bounding every $k$ between $1$ and $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ by $n/2$ and every $k$ between $\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1$ and $n$ by $n$, one gets, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$n!\leqslant\left(\frac{n}2\right)^{n/2-1}n^{n/2+1}=\frac{2n^n}{2^{n/2}},$$ hence $$\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{n^2}}\leqslant \frac{2^n}{2^{n^2/2}}\to0.$$

Comment: Can you show how you did bounding ? Because I can't see it how you got this inequality

Comment: Sure--which inequality? I thought every step was explained, so please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\ln(3n^2 + 20n + 5) = \ln(n^2) + \ln(3 + 20/n + 5/n^2)$$ and $$\ln(n^9 - 3n + 12) = \ln(n^9) + \ln(1 - 3/n^8 + 12/n^9).$$

See what to do now?

Answer (score 1):

For 1, use L'Hopital's rule. The limit is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so you can take the derivative of the top and the bottom to get the same answer. For 2 I would use Stirling's approximation of n!.